# Why are SSDs usually screwed in place in external cases?

Tags: ssd, m.2

It seems most external (USB) cases/readers for M.2 SSDs seem to opt for the design of screwing the SSD in place. It is also seemingly, somewhat irritatingly, often pointed at an angle away from the screwed-in part of the board.

I couldn't make sense of the thinking behind this design and couldn't find obvious google references to it.

1. What are some good reasons, most SSD cases use screws for M.2 drives? Do these reasons go beyond 'as-cheap-as possible design'?
2. Before the screws are in place, and after connecting it, the SSD is offset by a certain angle from the board (shown e.g. [here](https://youtu.be/AKed1OdLwvk?t=238)). Why is this?

Comment: I'm unsure why the downvote and no flag or comment, but guessing it's not relevant to the reader, will close if no one is interested in this

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking about. Are you wondering why the SSD PCB ends up non-parallel to the host PCB? Could you perhaps add a photo illustrating the issue? // M.2 cards are always fixated using screws.

Comment: @DanielB added a video from youtube as illustration and rephrased the question

Comment: That video is... let's just say it's not very good. You're supposed to insert the drive into the slot at an angle (you can see it springing to that angle at 4:02), then press it flat and screw it in. This way there's no pressure on the contact pads when the disk is being inserted. On the video they're basically scraping the pads off the board while damaging the connector.

Comment: I really don't recognize the problem. What alternative for securely mounting an M.2 SSD do you propose? SSDs are not meant to be removed from a motherboard or external case very often so using a screw seems to me a perfectly acceptable way to secure it. What do you mean by " pointed at an angle". On all motherboards or external cases I've seen, M.2 SSDs are mounted parallel to the board. You insert the SSD at an angle into the connector, then push it down to the screw terminal on the other end and it ends up flat and securely connected.

Comment: @StarCat there's really no problem, I just don't see why it's not just plug and play like, e.g. PCIe connectors (or any other known connector to me). I guessed there's a reason for that specific design choice (and want to understand this), but if not, then time to close the question... "pointed at an angle": it's visible in the 10s video, somewhat hard to capture with a picture. There is no debate here about the fact that it works (or it's somehow not an acceptable design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M2 SSDs operate faster than non-M2 SSDs and often have circuitry that throttles the speed of the drive when the temperature of the drive exceeds a preset level to prevent damage to the drive due to overheating. Installing the M2 SSD in a position that sets it away from the mounting printed circuit board improves the air circulation around the SSD and helps prevent throttling caused by overheating.